# Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE that runs on tomcat but it's fronted by an Apache server. I want to redirect users so that whenever they hit the old liferay URL, it redirects them to the new liferay URL. I changed the URL in liferay, so it is now the new URL. However, whenever I try to go to the old URL, I get a page request error. It never redirects me to the new URL. In `/san/apache/conf/` I put my redirect code inside of `httpd.conf`. This my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^group/old/(.*) /group/new/$1 [L]
```

After I applied these changes, I restarted the Apache server and it still doesn't work. I've tried a bunch of other combinations as well. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is there some place else I have to make this change?

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled?

Comment: yes, mod-rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, since your rewrite rule is lying in the server config file (instead of `htaccess` file), the mod-rewrite receives URLs with the leading slashes (`/`). So, the rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/group/old/(.*) /group/new/$1 [L]
```